# Cumulative sum of points for win loss teams?

Tags: python, r, database, multiple-columns, cumulative-sum

So I have multiple databases of sports and would like to cumulative sum of goals in two columns for the same text, not just one. In particular:

```
Year    team.Win    points.Win  team.Lose   points.Lose
1982    SUNY Cortland   2   Boston College  0
1982    Massachusetts   3   Rochester (NY)  1
1982    Princeton       1   George Mason    0
1982    Harvard         3   Brown           1
1982    Connecticut     2   SUNY Cortland   0
1982    UCF             2   Massachusetts   1
1982    North Carolina  4   Princeton       0
1982    Mo.-St. Louis   2   Harvard         1
1982    UCF             3   Connecticut     1
1982    North Carolina  2   Mo.-St. Louis   1
1982    Connecticut     2   Mo.-St. Louis   1
1982    North Carolina  2   UCF             0
```

should be

```
Year    team.Win    points.Win  team.Lose   points.Lose
1982    SUNY Cortland   2   Boston College          0
1982    Massachusetts   3   Rochester (NY)          1
1982    Princeton       1   George Mason            0
1982    Harvard         3   Brown                   1
1982    Connecticut     2   SUNY Cortland           2
1982    UCF             2   Massachusetts           4
1982    North Carolina  4   Princeton               1
1982    Mo.-St. Louis   2   Harvard                 4
1982    UCF             5   Connecticut             3
1982    North Carolina  6   Mo.-St. Louis           3
1982    Connecticut     5   Mo.-St. Louis           4
1982    North Carolina  8   UCF                     5
```

This is my first time on stackoverflow as a user! Sorry if the formatting isn't to the site's cup of tea. I came on to ask this question because I don't want to run a code that puts all numbers in the next column and cumulative sum from there. I just want to do it as is.

I have background in R, but I've been developing my skills in Python. I prefer the former. I am somewhat familiar with dplyr.

EDIT: I do NOT want this to be by year! Just run through all of the rows, and conduct a cumulative sum (in goals) based on the text values (teams).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach with `tidyverse` in R.

This approach involves putting the data into long form, so that cumulative points are calculated by team (including points from both wins and losses).

After that, put back into wide form. I hope this is helpful.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-Year, -rn), names_to = c(".value", "outcome"), names_pattern = "(\\w+).(\\w+)") %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  mutate(cum_points = cumsum(points)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Year, rn), names_from = c(outcome, outcome), values_from = c(team, cum_points), names_sep = ".") %>%
  select(Year, ends_with("Win"), ends_with("Lose"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
    Year team.Win       cum_points.Win team.Lose      cum_points.Lose
   <int> <chr>                   <int> <chr>                    <int>
 1  1982 SUNY_Cortland               2 Boston_College               0
 2  1982 Massachusetts               3 Rochester_(NY)               1
 3  1982 Princeton                   1 George_Mason                 0
 4  1982 Harvard                     3 Brown                        1
 5  1982 Connecticut                 2 SUNY_Cortland                2
 6  1982 UCF                         2 Massachusetts                4
 7  1982 North_Carolina              4 Princeton                    1
 8  1982 Mo.-St._Louis               2 Harvard                      4
 9  1982 UCF                         5 Connecticut                  3
10  1982 North_Carolina              6 Mo.-St._Louis                3
11  1982 Connecticut                 5 Mo.-St._Louis                4
12  1982 North_Carolina              8 UCF                          5
```